# Sending a geric notification in Laravel without a notifiable

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-notification

Normally when sending notifications in Laravel you send to a class with a `Notifiable` trait that defines "who" the notification is going to by the instance of the class. Such as with the User model.

I have a use case to send a notification to myself (the admin) and I don't have an entry in the User model.

Laravel does allow the use of the `route()` method using the Notification facade such as

`Notification::route('email', 'admin@myapp.example')->notify(new SomeLaravelNotification());`

However imo that's kinda verbose, is there a way to wrap the routing logic into the Notification class so I can just call something like

`Notification::send(new SomeLaravelNotification());`

Then I could have the routing logic as part of the `SomeLaravelNotification` class?